# cordova.js is not getting generated

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-cli

I have a cordova project
When I do a

```
cordova run android
```

the android project gets generated. But the cordova.js file is missing. 
The problem started after I added the cordova-plugin-dialogs plugin and built the cordova project. Post adding the plugin the js file is not getting generated.

When I manually add the cordova.js file to assets/www folder the apk runs fine via android studio.

I am not able to use command line to run my cordova android application.
Can you tell me why the cordova.js is not getting generated.

On a side note and possibly not related I added jcenter() to the list of repositories in the build.gradle of the generated CordovaLib project